# Why is my ComboBox ToolTip not in synch with the ComboBoxItem ToolTip all the time?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am trying to update the Combo ToolTip at the same time as the ComboItems.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboMeetingWeek" ItemsSource="{Binding Meetings}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Meeting, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                 Content="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.ToolTipForSpecialEvent}">
        </ToolTip>
    </ComboBox.ToolTip>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTipForSpecialEvent}">
                <Image Source="Images/Bell.png" Margin="0,0,5,0"
                       Visibility="{Binding DisplayBellImage, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenConverter}}" Stretch="None"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateMeetingAsText}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The ComboBoxItems will **always** be correct. The but the ComboBox ToolTip won't.

Comment: I think its because just hovering over an item doesn't set it as Selected, so when you bind to `SelectedItem.ToolTip` its showing you the SelectedItem, not the OnHover item.

Comment: @Rachel Thanks. I managed to sort it according to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution. I had to do it like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboMeetingWeek" ItemsSource="{Binding Meetings}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Meeting, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          ToolTip="{Binding Meeting.ToolTipForSpecialEvent}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTipForSpecialEvent}">
                <Image Source="Images/Bell.png" Margin="0,0,5,0"
                       Visibility="{Binding DisplayBellImage, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenConverter}}" Stretch="None"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateMeetingAsText}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Less code ... even better .. :) But now is **always** works right.

This [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/52ee62b4-41b6-44c1-8d2d-0243162266ef/problem-binding-combobox-tooltip-to-selected-item?forum=wpf) helped.